# ubuntu14.04 error when importing a module converted by f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, ubuntu-14.04, f2py

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I converted Fortran subroutine to a python module using f2py via numpy, and when I imported it in python2.7, I got an error message,

> undefined_symbol: __svml_cos4

when I imported it in python3, I got

> undefined_symbol: PyCObject_Type

While my colleague imported the same module in python on Gentoo Linux with no issue...

Here is the fortran code

```
subroutine   callsub(var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4)
implicit none
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ngr1 = selected_real_kind(p=7)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ngr2 = selected_real_kind(p=15)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ngi1 = selected_int_kind(r=9)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ngi2 = selected_int_kind(r=1)

integer(ngi1) var_1
real(ngr2) var_2(*)
logical var_3
character(*) var_4

call sub(var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4)
end
```

The "sub" is a complex subroutine using "libtobeused.a"

The conversion is done with

```
 f2py -c path/to/callsub.f90 -m callsub -L. -ltobeused
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some of the fortran code along with the python converted code?

Comment: Also, for clarification, you are using `f2py` via `numpy`?

Comment: more information has been added.

Comment: That looks like the library you are linking against has unmet dependencies  to the Intel Short Vector Math Library. You will need to add all of the required static dependencies when you build the library for Python